# How to edit placeholder of search form in LARAVEL

Tags: laravel, placeholder

I wanted to edit placeholder in search box in laravel but i can not find the exact location to edit it.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="q" id="btnItems" placeholder="Find photos: eg. 'Animals'">
```

Find photos: eg. 'Animals placeholder -- I can not find the directory in laravel web application, please help.

Answer (score 0):

In your routes/web.php file, look for the route serving the URL you requested
Go to the specified controller in app/http/controller,
Check for the function that's specified  along with the controller in your route/web.php file
The function should return a view, something like:
return view('view_name')
Search for the name inside the bracket in your resources/views directory

Comment: You're welcome. You can mark it as the accepted answer